# Should currency labels omit decimals for full dollars, i.e. $10 versus $10.00?

Tags: gui-design, currency

I need to show the User's balance in one of my iOS app , I am using inbuilt iOS API for currency representation, which gives me $10.00 for 10 balance, But my UI designer suggesting me it should be only $10 not $10.00 , Please help me to find out Which one is the Correct Currency representation

$10

or

$10.00

Comment: Is everything only ever going to be in full dollars, no cents? (i.e. will there ever be a balance of something like $10.35?)

Comment: cents are there, My UI designers' point is , if there is nothing in cents than it should truncate the decimal part.

Comment: quite hard to give an answer without knowing more about the UI (seeing it). but your UI designers "point" sounds more like an opinion. what are his arguments in favour for dropping the cents on 'round' balances?

Comment: @hemantchittora I'd see it as "if there is ***never*** anything in cents, then you should truncate the decimal part". If it's a price list or balance that always be in whole dollars, then show it as $10; but if any number is likely, then you should show $10.00 consistently with $11.11.

Answer (score 6):

A reasonable rule of thumb "remove everything you don't need" could be extracted from Nielsen's heuristic [Aesthetic and minimalist design](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/)

So flip the question around and ask why you would *need* to display cents if the data is a round dollar value? Two reasons I have to hand

1. Decimal alignment
2. Maintain the consistency usability heuristic

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3dDrL.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The 'remove everything you possibly can' rule of thumb is a useful razor, but can be misapplied.

Answer (score 1):

Every country has it's own currency format and rules for it. For example: does there need to by a space between the symbol and the amount, should the symbol be placed before or after the amount, should decimals be written after a comma or a point and so on. These rules ensure that currencies are not confusing and easy to read for everyone in a country. I should always stick to these rules to make sure amounts are easy recognizable.

Now, to answer your question. I think you're right and you should (always) write two decimals, even when they are zeros. For one, it makes the number easy recognizable as a currency. Sure there is a symbol for that, but this helps as well. Secondly, it also is a reference to the real world, where (in most countries) $0.01 is the lowest possible amount of money in coins. I base this on the country I live in, so it can be worthwhile to check if this is relevant for you. The only thing I can find is that there seems to be some difference between Canada and the US.